# Cannot change page in Android 4.0.3 (JQueryMobile + PhoneGap)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm unable to transition from index.html to any pages correctly. All transitions would show an almost empty page with LogCat showing:

"E/libEGL(17550): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)"

My code does not contain any video tag or anything like that. All pages work well if I set them as default page in super.loadUrl();

I've also tried on Android 2.3 it still have the same issue. I'm using PhoneGap1.5 and JQM 1.0.1.

Several others have reported the same issue and am wondering if there is any solution to this.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cannot-change-page-in-android-3-2-1-honeycomb-jqm-1-1-0
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/UNDY3cAJH34

**[Update]: I tried a separate project in Aptana without PhoneGap but just JQM. The problem still exists. It seems now is the problem of JQM itself.**

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your code - specifically how a sample link works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. It is due to JQM's ajax paging behavior. When I disabled the ajax, everthing works fine now.

Comment: Having this problem, can you explain what you mean with regards to disabling the ajax behaviour?

Comment: Hopefully @Yang will look at this :-)